# How to prevent call to base implementation of a method

Tags: c++, inheritance

Lets say we have following hierarchy:

```
class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Base : public Abstract
{
public:
    virtual void foo() override; //provides base implementation
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() override; //provides derived implementation
};
```

If `Base::foo()` is ever called on the `Derived` object that object will desync and its data will be corrupted. It inherits `Base`'s data structure and its manipulation but needs to perform additional operations so calling only the `Base::foo()` will omit these extra operations and as a result the `Derived`'s state will be corrupted.

Therefore I would like to prevent direct call of `Base` implementation of `foo` so this:

```
Derived d;
d.Base::foo();
```

ideally, should give me a compile time error of some sorts. Or do nothing or otherwise be prevented.

However it might be I am violating the polymorphism rules and should use composition instead but that would require a lots of extra typing...

Comment: Something wrong with `protected:` rather than `public:` for that method in `Base` ? And fwiw, this also seems a decent candidate for redeclaring as pure-virtual in `Base` *and* providing a `Base` implementation, which isn't common, but does happen. If `Derived` should *always* be implemented, it would seem a decent fit.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was not aware I could provide implementation for pure virtual method. Does that prevent that implementation to ever be called if it was reimplemented by those that inherit it?

Comment: @Resurrection no, that is why `protected` on `Base::foo` would come in. But what it *does* do is force derived classes to still provide overrides, while also providing a common Base implementation they can invoke without tossing an additional member function into the malaise.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh I see now. That is something to consider then. Hm. Thanks!

Comment: Another thing to consider is "how would this erroneous call happen?"  In general, you want to "protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli".

Comment: @MartinBonner Well it actually is a real concern in this case. Not because I would suspect someone outside would call it like this (although it is nice to be protected from that) but rather from the "inside" (i.e. derived classes and classes operating on them like views/controllers might accidentally make that call and it would be quite fatal). Hence the need to protect from it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
class Abstract
{
public:
    void foo() { foo_impl(); }
private:
    virtual void foo_impl() = 0;
};

class Base : public Abstract
{
private:
    virtual void foo_impl() override; //provides base implementation
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    virtual void foo_impl() override; //provides derived implementation
};
```

then

```
void test(Abstract& obj) {
    obj.foo();  // the correct foo_impl() will be invoked
}
Derived d;
test(d);  // impossible to call the foo_impl() of Base
```

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to hide polymorphism behind non-polymorphic template functions, not only in this case.

Answer (score 12):

You can explore the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). It allows for greater control of the execution of the methods involved.

```
class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Base : public Abstract
{
protected:
    virtual void foo_impl() = 0;
public:
    //provides base implementation and calls foo_impl()
    virtual void foo() final override  { /*...*/ foo_impl(); }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
protected:
    virtual void foo_impl() override; //provides derived implementation
};
```

The pattern is seen in the iostreams library with `sync()` and `pubsync()` methods.

To prevent the direct calls and maintain the consistent state, you will need to get the `final` implementation of the `foo` method in the correct place in the stack. If the intent is to prohibit the direct call from the top of the hierarchy, then you can move the `_impl` methods up.

See also the non-virtual interface, [the NVI pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern).

---

Bear in mind as well that the overriding methods do not have to have the same access specifier as the `Abstract` class. You could also just make the methods in the derived classes `private` or `protected`;

```
class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Base : public Abstract
{
    virtual void foo() override; //provides base implementation
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    virtual void foo() override; //provides derived implementation
};
```

*Note: unless otherwise intended, changing the access specifier could be considered bad design - so basically if you do change the access specifier, there should should be a good reason to do so.*

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have used this pattern before but for some reason it did not occur to me it would solve my current issue. Anyway, I think the virtual foo is an overkill in this case and non-virtual foo in Abstract with virtual foo_impl would suffice actually as suggested by the others. But yes, this is for when I would want to allow truly full control.

Comment: Sure, what level you hook in the template method pattern is dependent on what else you want to do. I placed it there since you mentioned that point in the question. Maintaining a class with only pure virtual functions can also be advantageous (it minimises linker dependency e.g. over a dll boundary).

Comment: Interesting point. I will consider it when rewriting it. Regarding the edit: that is certainly possible (although I read elsewhere it is a bad design to redaclare identifiers like that) but not in this case becasue Base must work as envisioned by Abstract so I cannot hide the public interface or parts of it in this case.

Comment: It is an alternative if you want to enforce the access. Unless otherwise intended, yes, changing the access specifier can be bad design - so basically if you do change the access specifier, there should should be a good reason to do so. I mention it as an alternative, but frankly I prefer the template method pattern and have used it successfully often and I favour the control it gives me.

Answer (score 8):

You can make all the `foo()` methods non-`public`, then have a non-`virtual` function in the `Abstract` class that simply calls `foo`.

Comment: For "can" read "probably should" (as a general rule - even when you aren't trying to prevent people shooting themselves in the foot).

Comment: @Martin Bonner - true, oblig. link [Non Virtual Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern) etc....